# Lenovo Legion Y720 laptop Keyboard backlight

Tags: lenovo, 18.04, keyboard-backlight

I just moved from Windows to Ubuntu, but I cannot get the keyboard backlight to work at all. On Windows there was a specific program for controlling the backlight. I have searched for days now without luck. Anyone got a solution?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Fabby this is not a duplicate. This is a gaming laptop and it has a non-standard keyboard backlight.

Comment: @kagronick That was more than a year ago and the duplicate votes have expired. Comment removed.  **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way for solving that, but it works only if you're dual booting.

First, boot into Windows, set the backlight as you want, then restart the computer the backlight will still be on. I've searched a lot and this seems the only way of doing it I've found that works for me.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, since the person asking the question doesn't have dual boot, this isn't really an answer to their question.

Answer (score 2):

I made a software that controls the Lenovo Legion Y720 keyboard backlight.

https://github.com/Izurii/Lenovo-Y720-KB-LED-Driver

It's made for Linux and right now it's working with Ubuntu 20.04

[Lenovo Y720 KB Controller Releases](https://github.com/Izurii/Lenovo-Y720-KB-Led-Controller/releases)

You can download and run the latest AppImage and change the keyboard settings or you can download de DEB package and install using `sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb` in a terminal, the software starts at login so you don't need to open every time you restart your PC, and the global hotkey <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (the same used in Lenovo Nerve Center) is working.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> to change between different modes, for me there's three:

- off
- normal on
- blazing sun on

Works on my Lenovo Y730. Hope it works.