# Keyboard backlight not working Lenovo Legion Y720

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, lenovo, keyboard-backlight

I have dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04LTS on 2 partitions of my SSD respectively.

The default red keyboard backlight comes on for a few seconds during BIOS startup but then disappears before GRUB menu.

No luck using `xset led 3` on terminal. No scrollkey on keyboard so I guess that isn't an option. Tried using the following bash file (got it from another question on Ask Ubuntu) but no luck:

I ran this using `./lights.sh`

[image: xset script]

On Windows I used to use a program called Lenovo Nerve Sense to control my RGB keyboard backlight. Perhaps we can configure it using Wine for Ubuntu?

I've already referred to this question: [Lenovo Legion Y720 laptop Keyboard backlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031547/lenovo-legion-y720-laptop-keyboard-backlight)

But this is not the right way of dealing with this problem. Also it doesn't work for me.

Your help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I made a software that controls the Lenovo Legion Y720 keyboard backlight.

https://github.com/Izurii/Lenovo-Y720-KB-Led-Controller

It's made for Linux and right now it's working with Ubuntu 20.04

[Lenovo Y720 KB LED Controller Releases](https://github.com/Izurii/Lenovo-Y720-KB-Led-Controller/releases)

You can download and run the latest AppImage and change the keyboard settings or you can download de DEB package and install using `sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb` in a terminal, the software starts at login so you don't need to open every time you restart your PC, and the global hotkey <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (the same used in Lenovo Nerve Center) is working.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this problem for years! Thanks a lot for your effort :)